# Chart js not display graph

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I use chart js to display my graph, but it wont displaying it...
I try to check it in jsfiddle and it works there, but on my website it actually wont work. 
The source from chart.js is correctly embedded, so i don't know what the error could be

[jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/heocfLks)

My code:

```js
var diemeltalsperrectx = document.getElementById('diemeltalsperre').getContext('2d');
var diemeltalsperre = new Chart(diemeltalsperrectx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [
      '08.05.2020 - 18:15:00',
      '09.05.2020 - 01:00:00',
      '09.05.2020 - 06:15:00',
      '09.05.2020 - 18:15:00',
      '10.05.2020 - 01:00:00',
      '10.05.2020 - 06:15:00',
    ],
    datasets: [{
      fill: true,
      label: 'Pegelstand (cm)',
      data: [
        374.91,
        374.9,
        374.9,
        374.87,
        374.87,
        374.84,
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(0,0,128, 1)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(0,0,128, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 3
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id='diemeltalsperre' width='800' height='400'></canvas>
```

Comment: No need to `.getContext('2d')`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The values ​​are very close to each other, try with:

```
beginAtZero:false
```

Comment: Ok, in this case you should show what happens on your site, if there are errors in console, etc ...